# Parse.com Development to Production Release iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, release, production, staging

We have been using parse.com as a BaaS for an enterprise deployed application, it's not going to be released to the Apple AppStore.

We are about to go live with it and I'm looking to see if I should release the application from 'Dev' to  'Production' in parse.

[image]

The only benefit I can see at the moment is if you mark it as production and provide the app store links parse.com will track App traffic and scale for performance. It's a tiny install base and we are not going to be in the App Store so no benefit here.

Am I missing something, is there any other reason for releasing to production in parse.com?

thx//56k

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add the tag [parse.com] to this question to make sure it has the visibility with the right audience.

I am not 100% sure but i dare say that apps that are marked as production are hosting on different environments (more failover etc) and so I think it is worth while marking it as such.

I find this blog entry which seems relevant http://blog.parse.com/2014/03/31/production-vs-development-apps/